# How to preserve previous frames when using FuncAnimation in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to animate the path of a particle and keep all of its previous positions so that I can see the whole trajectory and the movement of this particle at the same time. How can I do that with FuncAnimation?

Comment: Is there any indication that you cannot do it? What problem do you face?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The animation function erases the previous frame in each time step while I want to see the previous positions of the particle as well.

Comment: Sure, it *might* do that in case you told it so. If you want to provide a [mcve] of the problem you face, you can receive help here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok I'll do that.